# Issue generating custom filter for cpt admin columns

Tags: wp-query, filters, admin

I'm adding a custom dropdown filter to the admin cpt posts view.

I'm hooking in the action 'restrict_manage_posts' with the following function:

```
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'show_filters' );

function show_filters() {

    $tag = isset( $_GET[ 'partner' ] ) ? esc_attr( $_GET[ 'partner' ] ) : null;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'partner',
    );

    $partners_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $partners_options = array( '' => 'Choose partner' );

    if ( ! empty( $partners_query->posts ) ) {
        foreach ( $partners_query->posts as $partner ) {
            $partners_options[$partner->ID] = $partner->post_title;
        }
    } else {
        // Just for check that the query is returning empty
        $partners_options = array( '' => 'EMPTY QUERY: Debugging purposes' );
    }       

    if ( ! empty( $partners_options ) ) {

        echo '<select name="partner" class="postform">';

        foreach ( $partners_options as $id => $name ) {
            if( $name ) {
                printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', esc_attr( $id ), selected( $id, $tag, false), esc_html( $name ) );
            }
        }

        echo '</select>';
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** I have a pre_get_posts filter, that adds the meta_query to the filtering:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'orderby_filtering' );
function orderby_filtering( $query ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET[ 'partner' ] ) && $_GET[ 'partner' ] ) {
        $query->query_vars['meta_query'][] = array(
             'key'      => 'partner_select',
             'value'    => (int)$_GET[' partner ']
        );
    }
}
```

The filter works well, and it returns the correct values, but once executed, the new dropdown shows the "EMPTY QUERY" message instead of the partners list that should appear.

Why the query is not executed again? What I'm missing?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is because when I try your code the only way I get the "EMPTY QUERY" is where there are **NO** posts of that post type.  Could you have anything hooked into the WP_Query-related actions/filters (e.g., [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) that is altering the query **IF** `isset( $_GET[ 'partner' ] ) == true`?

Comment: I will give a try. Note that the "EMPTY QUERY" appears when I make some filtering choosing one value from the dropdown, not in the initial posts list screen, with no elements filtered at the moment.

Comment: @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron you were right! And I solve the problem, adding $query->is_main_query() to the conditional. If you want to publish the answer I will vote it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: we've _all_ been there.  glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably hooked into one of the WP_Query-related actions/filters (e.g., [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/)) and altering the query when `isset( $_GET[ 'partner' ] ) == true`.  Find a way to conditionally avoid that modification (e.g., checking if `$query->is_main_query()`).